# Recommended jobs API

Tags: linkedin-api

I am trying to retrieve recommended jobs for a user profile through LinkedIn API, as described [here](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/jobs/recommended-jobs).

As the API recently changed, I am wondering if it is still possible to have access to jobs. 
If so, how can i get the permission `r_JYMBII` (Required to retrieve recommended jobs.) for my app?

I tried to add this permission during [the 3 legged auth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authorization-code-flow?context=linkedin/context) but got an error message saying that the scope is unauthorized for my application. If this recommended jobs scope is no longer supported, is there any way to have access to jobs?